# Rails + SASS . How to list all imported files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, sprockets

I would like to stop importing my Sass files with Sprocket and using the @import function of Sass.
It works fine but the files are not imported one by one in developement mode so the debuging is harder.

Is there a way to import all files separately with Sass in developement mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable asset debugging in Sprockets by adding the setting to your `development.rb`:

```
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

When debug is true, compiled CSS files contain line numbers that tell you where to find the uncompiled CSS:

```
/* line 5, ../../../app/assets/stylesheets/_colors.scss */
.color-facebook-blue {
  color: #3B5998;
}
```